# If $a$ is $1$-periodic, then $\Delta(af) = a \Delta f$

Tags: calculus

Why if $a$ is 1-periodic, then $\Delta(af) = a \Delta f$ for any function $f$ ?

$$\Delta f(x)= f(x+1)-f(x)$$

Comment: What does $\Delta$ stand for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Delta (af)=(af)(x+1)-(af)(x)=\underbrace{a(x+1)}_{=a(x)}f(x+1)-a(x)f(x)=a(x)(f(x+1)-f(x))=a\Delta f $$

Comment: if $a$ is $1-$ periodic, then $a(x+1)=a(x)$.

Comment: i know but why $$(af)(x+1)-(af)(x){=a(x+1)}f(x+1)-a(x)f(x)$$

Comment: this is the definition if the multiplication of two functions on $\mathbb R$